# 指定したヘッダファイルがあるのに”No such file or directory”とエラーが出る。

Tags: vscode, esp32

現在Visual studio codeとplatformioを利用したESP用のプログラムの作成を勉強中です。

platformioのプロジェクトで次のようなエラーが発生します。

（エラー内容）
src\main.c:28:21: fatal error: lv_font.h: No such file or directory

”lv_font.h”ファイルがみつからないとのエラーですが、プロジェクトフォルダ内の/ESP32Test/include/src/lv_font/lv_font.h

このパスにこのファイルは有るはずなのですが、なぜこのようなエラーが出るのか、解決方法を教えてください。

（エラーの全体の内容）

> > Executing task in folder ESP32Test: C:\Users\kmaeh.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run
> > Processing esp32dev (platform: espressif32; board: esp32dev; framework: arduino)
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
> CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32dev.html
> PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (1.12.4) > Espressif ESP32 Dev Module
> HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
> DEBUG: Current (esp-prog) External (esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
> PACKAGES:
>
> - framework-arduinoespressif32 3.10004.200129 (1.0.4)
> - tool-esptoolpy 1.20600.0 (2.6.0)
> - toolchain-xtensa32 2.50200.80 (5.2.0)
>   LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> http://bit.ly/configure-pio-ldf
>   LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
>   Found 43 compatible libraries
>   Scanning dependencies...
>   Dependency Graph
>   |-- 
>   |   |-- <lv_arduino> 3.0.1
>   |-- <lv_arduino> 3.0.1
>   Building in release mode
>   Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.c.o
>   src\main.c:28:21: fatal error: lv_font.h: No such file or directory
>
> ---
>
> - Looking for lv_font.h dependency? Check our library registry!
> - 
> - CLI  > platformio lib search "header:lv_font.h"
> - Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:lv_font.h
> - 
>
> ---
>
> compilation terminated.
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_font\lv_font_montserrat_46.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_font\lv_font_montserrat_48.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_font\lv_font_simsun_16_cjk.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_font\lv_font_unscii_8.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_gpu\lv_gpu_stm32_dma2d.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_hal\lv_hal_disp.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_hal\lv_hal_indev.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_hal\lv_hal_tick.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_anim.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_area.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_async.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_bidi.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_color.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_debug.c.o
> Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\lv_arduino\src\lv_misc\lv_fs.c.o
> *** [.pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.c.o] Error 1
> ======================================================================================== [FAILED] Took 3.65 seconds ========================================================================================
> The terminal process "C:\Users\kmaeh.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe 'run'" terminated with exit code: 1.
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: インクルードパス（.hのファイルを探すフォルダーのリスト）が正しくないためだと思います。
lv_font.hというファイルは存在するのに、見つけられないというのが現状のエラーの状況で、探すべき場所(インクルードパス）を正してやれば、ファイルは見つかるはずです。
エラーが出るのがlv_font.hだけ(あるいは少数)なら、フルパス(C:から始まるファイルパス）にするという対処方法もあります。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。

Comment: c_cpp_properties.jsonを見てみると、lv_font.hファイルがあるパス
”D:\test\ESP32Test\include\lvgl\src\lv_font”
このパスが見当たらないことがわかりました。

Comment: https://qiita.com/sage-git/items/ffe463c0de05344d721b

こちらのサイトにあるようなインクルードパスの追加方法を実施しているのですが、なぜか追加されません。

Comment: 手動で追加する法などはありませんでしょうか？

Comment: #include <lv_font.h>
を
#include ”D:\test\ESP32Test\include\lvgl\src\lv_font\lv_font.h”
にすれば良いのでは？　
（先ほどのコメントで「フルパス」と書いたのは、上記のような意図です）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そういうやり方もできるのですね。助かります。